# can't figure out how to use reduce properly

Tags: javascript

My goal is:

```
var arr = [{name: 'Alex'},{name: 'Mia'},{name: 'David'}];
bz(arr,'areWeAwesome','shuAr')
```

This should change `arr` to:

```
[{name: 'Alex', areWeAwesome: 'shuAr'},{name: 'Mia', areWeAwesome: 'shuAr'},{name: 'David', areWeAwesome: 'shuAr'}];
```

And I actually know how to do this:

```
function bz(zarr,zkey,zval) {
    for(var i in zarr) {
        zarr[i][zkey] = zval;
    }
}
```

But I can't figure it out how to implement this with `reduce`... I just don't see it. I tried many variations, the last one is this:

```
function bzz(zarr,zkey,zval) {
    return zarr.reduce(function(acc,val){
        return acc[val[zkey] = zval]
    },[{}]);
}
```

I read about `reduce` in the MDN documentation, but it didn't help... I just can't get it... would appreciate if you could help me with this

Comment: does it has to be `reduce`?

Comment: @NinaScholz yeZ :)  Kinda learning it, so

Comment: reduce is not for this... you want to use map

Comment: Thanks a lot folks! I'm re-ally appreciate your help! btw, if there would be some newbies as I who don't know es6 yet, this may help: `function bzz(zarr,zkey,zval) {
 return zarr.reduce(function(acc,val){
  acc.push(val[zkey] = zval)
  return acc;
    },[]);
}` Finally figured it out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for a new object with the wanted key/value pair.

```js
function bz(array, key, value) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(Object.assign({}, o, { [key]: value })), []);
}

var arr = [{name: 'Alex'},{name: 'Mia'},{name: 'David'}];
console.log(bz(arr,'areWeAwesome','shuAr'));
```

With [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which is preferable, because it returns an array with a value for each item of the given array.

```js
function bz(array, key, value) {
    return array.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { [key]: value }));
}

var arr = [{name: 'Alex'},{name: 'Mia'},{name: 'David'}];
console.log(bz(arr,'areWeAwesome','shuAr'));
```

Comment: Danke shon, Nina! :D

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be using reduce for this...

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Alex'},{name: 'Mia'},{name: 'David'}];

const bz = (arr, prop, value) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, e) => {
    acc.push({ [prop]: value, ...e });
    return acc;
  }, []);


console.log(bz(arr,'areWeAwesome','shuAr'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative:

The function `concat` allows you to concatenate the previously elements with a new one, on the other hand, the function `Object.assign` assigns new properties to the current object.

```js
function bz(arr, key, value) {
  return arr.reduce((a, c) => (a.concat(Object.assign({}, c, {[key]: value}))), []);
}

var arr = [{name: 'Alex'},{name: 'Mia'},{name: 'David'}];
console.log(bz(arr,'areWeAwesome','shuAr'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

However, a better approach is using the function `map`:

```js
function bz(arr, key, value) {
  return arr.map((c) => Object.assign({}, c, {[key]: value}));
}

var arr = [{name: 'Alex'},{name: 'Mia'},{name: 'David'}];
console.log(bz(arr,'areWeAwesome','shuAr'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `map` for this and not `reduce`.

The main reason, is that reduce is supposed to "reduce" things to one value (ie. add numbers) and not add things to arrays.

A `map` will iterate through an array, make any changes and return a new copy of that array with the changes for you.

But to answer your question, here is some code which will work for you:

```
function bzz(zarr,zkey,zval) {
    return zarr.reduce(function(acc,val){
        val[zkey]=zval;
        acc.push(val);
        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.